# Prevent committing filenames with platform-specific illegal characters in git

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

We often have issues with users accidentally committing files which have platform-spcecific illegal characters in their names. E.g. a user on Mac OS X is committing a file with name `file-name?xyz`, which causes trouble on Windows platforms which obviously always treat the `?` character as wildcard.

This leads to chaos on the respective clients and we currently always need to fix names on the platform, where the commit was originally done (e.g. renaming `file-name?xyz` to `file-name-xyz`).

Is there any mechanism which would completely prevent committing/pushing problematic file names? (either directly via git, or via Bitbucket Server)

Comment: You can add a hook to check if commit has valid file name. Check about hooks at https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: Thanks for answers, I'll have a look at this plugin for Bitbucket: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.christiangalsterer.stash-filehooks-plugin/server/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to create a personalised hook: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making a hook, like pedro suggets.

Below is a `precommit` hook that I've made. It's based on the sample that's included with Git For Windows (or Sourcetree or Bitbucket, I'm not sure where it came from).

Place the following in a file called `precommit` inside `.git/hooks/` from the project root:

```
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments.  The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
# it wants to stop the commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit".

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
fi

# If you want to allow non-ASCII filenames set this variable to true.
allownonascii=$(git config --bool hooks.allownonascii)

# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2

# Cross platform projects tend to avoid non-ASCII filenames; prevent
# them from being added to the repository. We exploit the fact that the
# printable range starts at the space character and ends with tilde.
if [ "$allownonascii" != "true" ] &&
    # Note that the use of brackets around a tr range is ok here, (it's
    # even required, for portability to Solaris 10's /usr/bin/tr), since
    # the square bracket bytes happen to fall in the designated range.
    test $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A -z $against |
      LC_ALL=C tr -d '[ !#-)+-9;=@-[]-{}~]\0' | wc -c) != 0
then
    cat <<\EOF
Error: Attempt to add a non-ASCII file name.

This can cause problems if you want to work with people on other platforms.

To be portable it is advisable to rename the file.

If you know what you are doing you can disable this check using:

  git config hooks.allownonascii true
EOF
    exit 1
fi

# If there are whitespace errors, print the offending file names and fail.
exec git diff-index --check --cached $against --
```

The bit I've changed is where it says:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -d '[ !#-)+-.0-9;=@-[]-{}~]\0' | wc -c) != 0
```

It used to say:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -d '[ -~]\0' | wc -c) != 0
```

The original removes all ascii characters in all the filenames and checks that there are no characters left (they were all ascii characters). If there were any left they were non-ascii characters and it errors and stops the commit.

My change just means it doesn't remove the characters `\/:*?">?|` and errors if not empty. That is, if there are non-ascii character, or any of those characters, it won't allow the commit.

You might want to change the comments in the file to explain the new functionality, if you use the file directly.

**EDIT:** There was a bug in the script. It would block the commit if it found a `/` in the files, but as it's looking at full paths, this would break if you were trying to submit anything not in the root on Mac or Unix. I've updating the code below, so should work properly.